# Rename [rct-classic] => [rollercoaster-tycoon-classic]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

I think the old name should live as a synonym. Let's rename [rct-classic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rct-classic) to [rollercoaster-tycoon-classic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rollercoaster-tycoon-classic).

Also I, uh, inadvertently created [roller-coaster-tycoon-classic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/roller-coaster-tycoon-classic) (note the - in *roller-coaster*), so I'd appreciate that being made a synonym as well. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've merged and synonymized [rct-classic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rct-classic) to [rollercoaster-tycoon-classic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rollercoaster-tycoon-classic)

I think the extra dash one got removed as it doesn't currently exist, and as the same tag name with different dashes (or dashes in different places) are already treated the same way by the system I didn't add the second synonym.